# Should I use pointer here?

Tags: c++, pointers

Let`s create three classes:

Class Vector3d:

```
class Vector3d{
    int a,b,c;
}
```

Class Face, every Face contains 3 vector:

```
class Face{
    Vector3d *a, *b, *c;
}
```

And class Mesh(3d object): in class mesh i can just get vector of faces, but most object of Vector3d class will be shared between many Faces so I`d like to store Vector3d in Mesh class and store only pointer in Face object;

```
class Mesh{
    std::vector<Vector3d> points;
    std::vector<Face> faces;
}
```

Problem is, that i don`t understand when should I delete pointer in Face class, should I use something else instead of this?

Edit:
3 int are just to explain my concept, in final verison there will be more data in Vector3d class

Comment: If you are trying to save memory, is that really necessary? Introducing pointers can slow down the execution of your code. If you point to 3d vectors inside `points` you don't have to delete the pointer. Because the memory is already managed by the std::vector. Be aware that resizing the `points` array may invalidate all your pointers to it.

Comment: You can use smart pointers. Search for unique_ptr, shared_ptr and weak_ptr.

Comment: To save memory? Although a valid concern, note that 3 `int` usually takes 12 bytes, and a pointer usually takes 8 bytes. The difference is not that large.

Comment: 3 int are just to explain concept. In final version there will bo more data stored in this class 
@E.vanPutten

Comment: @kol smart pointers are not a good solution here. There is no shared ownership and for the unique ownership of the points there's the vector

Comment: @Sopel No shared ownership? "most object of Vector3d class will be shared between many Faces"

Comment: @kol shared usage. Not shared ownership. The mesh will always outlive the faces and is the sole owner of the points.

Answer (score 6):

`Face` should store ***indices***, not pointers.
I.e. `Face` should have three members:
`unsigned a,b,c;`

Indices are safe if you add/remove/resize the `Vector3d` vector.
It also allows you to share points between faces in a more convenient way.

It also means you can copy the conents of your `faces` vector directly into a Graphics API buffer (taking granted types match).

Comment: I'd use `std::size_t` or `std::ptrdiff_t` instead of `unsigned`, but your point is good.

Comment: personally, I'd use `size_t` aswell, but most graphics API only have 16-bit or 32-bit indices (D3D11 for example). `uint32_t` or `uint16_t` would be more suited for the graphics APIs

Comment: Then, a,b,c will be index of Vector3d in std::vector or what? Google leads me to array's tutorial

Comment: @HeroesVII yes, like this: `Vector3d a = points[faces[i].a];`

Comment: This is the only answer that not only presents a good solution but also one tailored to the domain.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that using indices can possibly reduce the memory footprint (and effectively better utilize bandwidth) as pointers are restricted to a single size, while indices might use smaller integer types if the requirements allow.